# Is there a way to make the window in df.rolling dynamic depending on which row it is calculating for?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset of stock prices, and I want to add a column of 52 week lows for each day, however for the rows which dont have 365 days above them I just want the column to have the rolling min using whatever amount of rows exist above.

I was trying code like this, but this obviously doesnt work because its creating the column twice.

```
for row in data.iterrows():
  if row[0] < (data.index[0] + timedelta(days = 365)):
    data['52wkLow'] = data['Low']['GME'].rolling((row[0]-data.index[0]).days).min()
  elif row[0] > (data.index[0] + timedelta(days = 365)):
    data['52wkLow'] = data['Low']['GME'].rolling(365).min()
```

Here is an example of the data im wanting to get the rolling min for:

```
Date
2021-01-04     17.250000
2021-01-05     17.370001
2021-01-06     18.360001
2021-01-07     18.080000
2021-01-08     17.690001
2021-01-11     19.940001
2021-01-12     19.950001
2021-01-13     31.400000
2021-01-14     39.910000
2021-01-15     35.500000
2021-01-19     39.360001
2021-01-20     39.119999
2021-01-21     43.029999
2021-01-22     65.010002
2021-01-25     76.790001
2021-01-26    147.979996
2021-01-27    347.510010
2021-01-28    193.600006
2021-01-29    325.000000
2021-02-01    225.000000
2021-02-02     90.000000
2021-02-03     92.410004
2021-02-04     53.500000
2021-02-05     63.770000
2021-02-08     60.000000
2021-02-09     50.310001
2021-02-10     51.200001
2021-02-11     51.099998
2021-02-12     52.400002
2021-02-16     49.509998
2021-02-17     45.939999
2021-02-18     40.689999
2021-02-19     40.590000
2021-02-22     46.000000
2021-02-23     44.970001
2021-02-24     91.709999
2021-02-25    108.730003
2021-02-26    101.739998
2021-03-01    120.400002
2021-03-02    118.180000
2021-03-03    124.180000
2021-03-04    132.350006
2021-03-05    137.740005
2021-03-08    194.500000
2021-03-09    246.899994
2021-03-10    265.000000
2021-03-11    260.000000
2021-03-12    264.500000
2021-03-15    220.139999
2021-03-16    208.169998
2021-03-17    209.809998
Name: GME, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `.rolling(365, min_periods=1)` no need of for loop

```py
data['52wkLow'] = data['Low']['GME'].rolling(365,min_periods=1).min()
```